# Python ijson - nested parsing

Tags: python, json, parsing, ijson

I'm working with a web response of JSON that looks like this (simplified, and I can't change the format):

```json
[
   { "type": "0","key1": 3, "key2": 5},
   { "type": "1","key3": "a", "key4": "b"},
   { "type": "2", "data": [<very big array here>] }
]
```

I want to do two things:

1. Inspect the first two objects without reading everything to memory, I can do this by using Ijson:

```
parsed = ijson.items(res.raw, 'item')
next(parsed) # first item
next(parsed) # second item
```

2. Inspect the third object without putting it all to memory.
   If I do `next(parsed)` again, all of the "data" array will be read to memory and turned into a dict, and I want to avoid it.
3. Inspect the data array without loading it all to memory. If I didn't care about the other keys, I could do that:

```
parsed = ijson.items(res.raw, 'item.data.item') # iterator over data's items
```

The problem is, I need to do all of these on the same stream.

Ideally it would have been great to receive the third object as a file-like object that I can pass to ijson again, but that seems out of scope for that API.

I'm also fine with replacing ijson with a library that can do this better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ijson's [event interception mechanism](https://github.com/ICRAR/ijson#intercepting-events). Basically go one level down in the parsing logic by using `ijson.parse` until you hit the big array, then switch to using `ijson.items` with the rest of the `parse` events. This uses a string literal, but should illustrate the point:

```py
import ijson

s = b'''[
   { "type": "0","key1": 3, "key2": 5},
   { "type": "1","key3": "a", "key4": "b"},
   { "type": "2", "data": [1, 2, 3] }
]'''
parse_events = ijson.parse(s)
while True:
    path, name, value = next(parse_events)
    # do stuff with path, name, data, until...
    if name == 'map_key' and value == 'data':
        break
for value in ijson.items(parse_events, 'item.data.item'):
    print(value)
```

Comment: Being able to re-use the `parse_events` object in the `items` call was the missing piece for me.